# Strange green and gold coloured chemical

Tags: identification, dye

I have a reagent bottle with an unknown chemical that came with some other lab gear about 30 years ago, I stumbled on it again when clearing out some old stuff.

It is a standard brown glass Merck of about 250ml size.  It has no label and never had any indication of a label and I do not know if it is the original bottle.

The powder is a fine dark free flowing crystalline solid.  It is DARK green with a gold iridescent sheen when in bright light, something like a butterfly wing or some anti-forgery inks on banknotes.

Yet if I wet a very small portion it dissolves completely and creates a vivid dark blue solution that dries blue in a thin film.  If the crystals dry in a clump they form a smutty dark green gold pasty lump that is reminiscent of the original bulk colour.

I had to hand some potassium permanganate crystals and when I mixed a pinch of the two together and added a drop of water a gas evolved and the colour seemed to be somewhere between the permanganate and the mystery chemical blue when spread on paper.  Adding a few drops of acetic acid seemed to have no effect.

Can anyone think of an obvious candidate or some simple experiments that could be used to determine the material?

Comment: A picture would really help IMHO...

Comment: In general, I don't advise experiments on unknown substances, particularly because it is unknown.

Comment: @Zhe But we wouldn't know what we're dealing with *until* we "experiment" >:-D

Comment: That's true, but frankly, from a safety perspective, that's strongly ill-advised.  Will your analysis liberate hydrogen cyanide? Probably not, but for unknown substances, without a lot of context, you can't really know for sure.

Comment: The pasty lump seems to indicate an organic molecule. Obviously with quite an extended conjugation. Why not to proceed with analysis?  Obviously with an eye at safety first. I mean really go through solubility test,  Lassaigne. ... It seems you are in a lab....

Comment: Does it dissolve in ethanol or acetone? A photo of the substance and its aqueous solution would probably help.

Answer (score 5):

I worked for a time with squaraine dyes that were often greenish in the crystalline state, but ink-blue when in solution.

[image: Squaraine dyes]

However, I would suggest that you take an analytical approach to identifying this compound.  Have you done any NMR, IR or even UV/Vis spectroscopy?  Elemental analysis?

These would be a much safer way to go about identifying the mystery compound.

Good luck, and I'd love to know what you discover!

Comment: Cool, never heard of these but it is a likely candidate.   The colour shifting seems to be common with them depending on solvents and concentration  -  https://www.chm.uri.edu/levinegroup/documents/pub2.pdf